# Vue 3 - Composition API - Dynamically add template with text interpolation

Tags: typescript, vue.js, templates, vue-composition-api, string-interpolation

I have a Component that take a string property, like this:

```
<script lang="ts" setup>

    const props = defineProps<{
        transcription?: string;
    }>();
    
     watch(() => props.transcription,
         (newTranscription) => {
             if (newTranscription) {
                 console.log(newTranscription);
                 // dynamically ad paragraph with text interpolation
                 // `<p> {{ newTranscription }} </p>`
             }
          }
     );

</script>
<template>
    <h1>Transcriptions</h1>
    ...here i want to append a paragraph every time transcription has text
</template>
```

Whenever the property contains text I would like to add a "`<p> {{transcription}} </p>`" to the template that displays the text and changes based on the property content. The append must be dynamic.
Any suggestions will be appreciated

Comment: Please clarify more your use case

Comment: As simple as it sounds, I would like to be able to append N paragraphs to the template of my component, each one bound with a property passed by the parent. Don't overwrite but rather append a new paragraph every time. I hope I was clearer :)

Comment: You have a typo in your props definition: trascription should be tra**n**scription.

Comment: TNX I will edit ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a computed property :

```html
<script lang="ts" setup>

    const props = defineProps<{
        transcription?: string;
    }>();
    
   const newTranscription = computed(() => {
             if (props.transcription) {
                 return props.transcription + "some dynamic content"
             }
     );

</script>
```

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand your suggestion, I made some changes to the question to clarify

Answer (score 0):

Build an array of transcriptions, like:

```
<script lang="ts" setup>
    const transcriptions = [];

    const props = defineProps<{
        trascription?: string;
    }>();
    
     watch(() => props.trascription,
         (newTranscription) => {
             if (newTranscription) {
                 console.log(newTranscription);
                 //dynamically ad paragraph with text interpolation
                 transcriptions.push(newTranscription);
             }
          }
     );

</script>
```

And use `v-for` in your template:

```
<p v-for="transcr in transcriptions" :key="transcr">{{transcr}}</p>
```

Be aware that the key should be unique, which may not be the case in the example above.

Comment: I tried this way but the property is only one and is filled with text (from SpeechRecognition) that must be displayed in the paragraph just added. When the speechrecognition ends the property is emptied. At the next speechrecognition the variable is filled in again and a new paragraph must be added